# How can I turn my SELECT INNER JOIN into an UPDATE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been trying to turn my SELECT INNER JOIN into an UPDATE.
The query I've made in BigQuery is as follows:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM `table` tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT c_id, MIN(c_orderid) as OrderID, MIN(c_orderdate) AS MinDateTime
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY c_id) groupedtt 
ON tt.c_orderid = groupedtt.OrderID
AND tt.c_orderdate = groupedtt.MinDateTime
```

I want to turn this query into an update where it updates `c_first_sale` and sets it to `TRUE`.

The query I came up with is:

```
UPDATE `table` tt
SET tt.c_first_sale = TRUE
FROM `table` as dd
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT c_id, MIN(c_orderid) as OrderID, MIN(c_orderdate) AS MinDateTime
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY c_id) groupedtt 
ON dd.c_orderid = groupedtt.OrderID
AND dd.c_orderdate = groupedtt.MinDateTime
WHERE 1 = 1
```

But that gives me the following error

> UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

I feel like I'm pretty close, but I'm getting stuck on this.

Comment: In MySQL it should be `UPDATE tablename as T0 JOIN ( {your query} ) AS t1 ON t0.id = t1.id SET t0.column = newvalue;`. *But that gives me the following 'Error'* It seems that you use BQ - in this case [mysql] tag is errorneous and must be removed.

Comment: I've seen the suggested edit, but it appears that I'm unable to change the post and/or remove the mysql tag.

I've tried your query but it wants the SET value after the UPDATE.
'Syntax error: Expected keyword SET but got keyword JOIN at [2:1]'
If I do this, it says that it has an unexpected JOIN.

Comment: Of course, the syntax which is valid in MySQL is not valid in BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @Pale, Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hey @ShipraSarkar I eventually got it to work via a different method. The error code I got back from bigquery being 'UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row' told me that I could not update a selection if it contained multiple rows.
Instead I grouped by ID, exported those values and imported them in a different table. Then just told the query to update all the values in the main table where ID was X from the temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Pale, this error occurs when you try to update a table by updating joins with more than one row from the FROM clause as given in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#from_keyword). You can create a separate temporary table, perform a group by using an ID column and export the values into the temporary table. Perform join operation on both the tables using the ID column.